# Openshift custom domain addition

Tags: dns, openshift

How can i add my own custom domain to my service?
Now it has an openshift generated domain.

Comment: Which OpenShift version are you referring to? Older version 2, or new version 3 which is in developer preview at the moment?

Comment: sorry, i meant openshift3, developer preview

Comment: If OpenShift 3, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39099676/how-to-add-a-custom-hostname-for-project-in-openshift-online-next-gen-develope